# Batch Class running for multiple iterations

Tags: apex, batch

When I run the bacth class below through Developer COnsole, I see that the batch class generates 100's of emails though the specify batch size as 1. Can some one help me with this

```
global class BatchEmail implements Database.Batchable<SObject>
{

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
            SELECT Id,Contact__c,Group__c FROM Member__c WHERE CreatedDate = N_DAYS_AGO:1 and Contact__r.Date__c>=2017-08-31
        ]);
    }
        Map<Id,String> contact = new Map<Id,String>();
        Set<Id> Student = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> sol = new Set <Id>(); 
        public Map<Id,Id> Comm = new Map <Id,Id>();
        List<Id> CId = new List<Id>();
        Map<Id, Id> getUser = new Map<Id, Id>();
        List<Line__c> Rep = new List<Line__c>();

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Member__c> scope){
        system.debug('scope'+scope.size());         

       for(Line__c l : [Select Receipt__r.Contact__c,
                                              Receipt__r.Contact__r.Type__c,Receipt__r.Contact__r.Catgory__c,
                                            Is_Renew__c,Receipt__r.Contact__r.Id, Id From Line__c where CreatedDate = N_DAYS_AGO:1]){
            system.debug('create list');
            CId.add(l.Receipt__r.Contact__c);  
            Rep.add(l);
        }
        for(User U : [Select u.ContactId, u.Id From User u where u.ContactId IN : CId]){
            getUser.put(U.ContactId,U.Id);          
        }
        for(Line__c l : Rep){               

                if(l.Is_Renew__c == False){
                    contact.put(l.Receipt__r.Contact__c, l.Receipt__r.Contact__r.Type__c);
                                                          }
        }
        for(Contact pContact : [Select Id,Type__c,Catgory__c,Date__c From 
                                      Contact where Id IN : contact.keyset() and Join_Date__c >=2017-08-31]){ 
                                            if(contact.get(pContact.Id) == 'xxx' && pContact.Catgory__c == 'xxx'){
                                            sol.add(pContact.Id);
                                            }else if (contact.get(pContact.Id) =='xxx'){
                                                Student.add(pContact.Id);
                                            }

          for (Member__c m : [Select Id,Contact__c,Group__c from Member__c where CreatedDate = N_DAYS_AGO:1]){
                                if (m!=null){
                                comm.put(pContact.Id,m.Group__c);   
                                }                                                                               
                            } 

                                      }
    String urlInstance = String.valueof(System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL());
                                 List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
                                 List<String> email = new List<String>();                               
                                 EmailTemplate templateId = [Select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'xxx'];

                                 for (Id keyvalue : lComm.keyset())
                                 {  
                                 OrgWideEmailAddress owa = [select id, DisplayName, Address from OrgWideEmailAddress limit 1];
                                 for(Group__c Group : [Select Id, (Select c.Member__r.Email From Committs__r c where c.Date__c <= TODAY and c.Thrugh_Date__c >= TODAY  and c.Code__c IN ('X','N','L','LPP')) From Group__c g
                                                    where Id = : lComm.get(keyvalue)]){

                                    if(!Student.contains(keyvalue)){
                                            if(!sol.contains(keyvalue)){

                                            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                                            for(Committe__c comt : Group.Commites__r){
                                                email.add(comt.Member__r.Email);
                                            }
                                            system.debug(email.size());
                                            mail.setToAddresses(email);
                                            mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owa.id);
                                            mail.setTargetObjectId(keyvalue);
                                            mail.setTemplateID(templateId.Id); 
                                            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false); 
                                            mails.add(mail);


                                    }
                                                    }
                            }         
                                 Messaging.sendEmail(mails);


                                 }
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on how many rows you iterate through, that makes sense. 

Batch size of one means you will be processing one `Member__c` record at a time and, from what I can see, you're sending an email at the end of every batch. 

If you have 100s of members, you will get 100s of emails.

Comment: But for 1 member record processing, I am receiving 10-15 emails

Comment: The batch number in this case has nothing to do with your problem, then. I see the `mails.add(mail);` is inside of a for-loop. There must be a logic problem in your code. I don't have the context to debug it for you.

Comment: Sebastian, If I remove that statement out of the loop, there is no email that I could receive.

Comment: I believe, that Member__c is queried twice and that might be causing the issue. In the for loop, I had the query.

Answer (score 0):

First thought: Looking over the loops around the mailing section, I see lComm been looped through but I don't see it being defined anywhere.

My logic is seeing that since you're using a keyset to define "keyvalue" then it can't be referenced more than once (because of how sets work) but you're looping through all Committe__c records under the matching group.  Is it possible that one Member__c is referenced in more than one Committe__c, which would make them get duplicate emails but they're not really dupes?